# Unused import statement 'import config' Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm

```
class Bot:

    @staticmethod
    def token():
        telegramtoken = '...'
        return telegramtoken

    @staticmethod
    def executar():
        import config  # bot configs


Bot.executar()
```

why am i getting this error? if `import config` is working normally? is it possible to remove this warning?

Comment: `why am i getting this error` - what error? Post the stacktrace

Comment: Because `config` is local to that function, and as such, isn't used anywhere else. You should never import inside functions anyway.

Comment: how should i do it then? I wanted to create a simple command to run the bot, without having to directly run config.py

Comment: Import it at the top of the module, and use it somewhere. The warning exists to tell you that it's unnecessary.